# Understanding disassembled C code: 16 bytes stack allocation, movl $0x0,-0x4(%ebp) and nop

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to understand the lines in a piece of disassembled code as shown below. I'd like to know the following:

- `sub    $0x10,%esp` : Why are we allocating 16 bytes on top of the stack? I was expecting only 4 bytes for the pointer variable.
- `movl   $0x0,-0x8(%ebp)` : Why are we moving the value 0x0 onto the stack? Is this the start address of the binary?
- `nop` : What is the purpose of the nop instruction in this code?

Here's the disassembled binary:

```
Contents of section .text:
 0000 5589e583 ec10c745 fc000000 0090c9c3  U......E........
Contents of section .rodata:
 0000 48656c6c 6f00                        Hello.          
Contents of section .comment:
 0000 00474343 3a202855 62756e74 7520352e  .GCC: (Ubuntu 5.
 0010 342e302d 36756275 6e747531 7e31362e  4.0-6ubuntu1~16.
 0020 30342e31 30292035 2e342e30 20323031  04.10) 5.4.0 201
 0030 36303630 3900                        60609.          
Contents of section .eh_frame:
 0000 14000000 00000000 017a5200 017c0801  .........zR..|..
 0010 1b0c0404 88010000 1c000000 1c000000  ................
 0020 00000000 10000000 00410e08 8502420d  .........A....B.
 0030 054cc50c 04040000                    .L......        

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <my_function>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
   6:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%ebp)
   d:   90                      nop
   e:   c9                      leave  
   f:   c3                      ret
```

Here's the C code:

```c
void my_function () { 
   char* my_string = "Hello";
}
```

Comment: Is this code from an object file (`.o`) that was compiled without optimization?

Comment: The code was built without optimizations. Likely the use of subtracting 16 was related to the 64-bit System V ABI that mandates 16 byte alignment on function calls. You appear to be dumping an object file. The `c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%ebp)` has a value of 0 being moved since it is a place holder that will be relocated. Use the `-r` option with `objdump` to have it dump out relocation entries. If you were to dump an executable the relocation should be fixed up.

Comment: The `nop` in this case is some kind of artifact generated by some versions of GCC when compiling without optimizations. Turn on optimizations and it should disappear along with the rest of the function ;-)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/0OP6s4 - ayyy

Comment: @melpomene : I suggested in my comment optimizations on would probably eliminate the body of the function as you do nothing with the character string. Try making `my_string` a `volatile` pointer to force it to generate code for that string variable. As an example: https://godbolt.org/z/JCFEsl

Comment: Following Michael's comment, I can see the relocation entries. I can set the stack allocation to 4 bytes using the flag -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2, but the nop artifact still remains. Optmisation removes the function completely. Using x86 gcc 1.27 on godbolt, it removes the nop instruction and only 4 bytes is allocated for the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't explain the `nop` but for the rest

First, let's note that `char* my_string` is a local variable — that means it is stack allocated, and we can see it is at `-4(%ebp)`.  While not strictly necessary, the compiler is using a frame pointer for local variable access (instead of using the `%esp` directly).

Next, let's observe that `"hello"` is a string literal — and that string literals are constants stored in the `.rodata` section.

And finally let's observe that your disassembler is not printing relocations from `.text` to `.rodata` in a meaningful way so it simply says `0` for the address of `"hello"` in the instruction.  If it was printing them better, that 4 bytes of 0's in the `movl` instruction would have the address of `.rodata + 0`, the address that is the value we want to move into `my_string`.

As far as the choice of 16 bytes, the compiler is simply rounding up.  There are good reasons to round up but they are not obvious here.  The total stack space used is 4 bytes for the return address plus 4 for the old `%ebp`, plus the 16.  At least the total is a multiple of 8, which is good for alignment, as that makes it easy to have 8 byte values on the stack being 8 byte aligned.

Comment: Using `objdump -dr` will print relocation info so you can usefully use it on a `.o`